# Pass setter value to constructor

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, jbpm

I need to pass a setter value (set by jbpm call) to a contructor in Java. Is it possible? 
JBPM calls a constructor with no arguments. So my only way out is to set that value and pass it as a parameter to contructor? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show code or configuration?

Comment: Yes, very difficult to figure out what you need without code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the concept of [Parametrized constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). You can create a object using the parametrized constructor and call the default one from it, like

```
class MainClass {
    String name;
    public MainClass(){
        System.out.println("In default constructor");
    }

    public MainClass(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.println("In constructor with a String");
    }
}
```